# Creating an electric alarm

Tags: timer

I usually forget to turn off the geyser. To solve this problem, I want to create an alarm that will go off, 10 minutes after I have turned on the switch for the geyser. I'm a computer science student. So I'm not sure how do I even start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just set an alarm in your phone, it is the easiest one. If you want to create something just to get some experience with it, look around on the internet first and do some more research.

Comment: Is this a 'real' problem you're trying to solve? Seems like an XY problem - why do you believe that it's necessary for you to be turning your geyser (aka water heater) on and off regularly? Surely it has a functioning thermostat and is reasonably well insulated against heat loss...

Comment: @brahns This seems pretty common in developing countries. Even in an Airbnb apartment in a nice area of Mexico City I had to exit the apartment and start a gas water heater in the inner courtyard.

Comment: There are dozens of different ways to set an alarm: your phone, Amazon Echo Dot, alarm clock, kitchen timer, microwave oven or stove timer, etc. What about these are not working for you ?

Comment: @JonathanG I don't think you have understood the problem, I want a solution in which I don't have to do anything extra, I will just turn on the switch of the geyser, Maybe between the way there is an alarm connected, which gets activated as soon as it receives power, and after 10 mins it goes off. mobile alarm would need me to be with my mobile at that time, also would require me to set it manually. I don't want to do that effort.

Comment: @brhans yes it is a real problem, I don't have an auto power cut in my geyser.

Comment: @Hilmar do you usually bring your microwave oven to the bathroom ?

Comment: Ok - but you haven't answered the 2nd part of my question: why do you believe that it's *necessary* to be turning your geyser on & off at all?

Comment: @brhans I believe the geyser I'm using consumes energy if the power is on, so many times when I forget to turn off the geyser, it actually consumes a lot of power resulting in a electricity bill which makes me cry.

Comment: Okay, I'm curious. What on earth is a geyser in this context?

Comment: Buy an **egg timer**, mount the timer close to the geyser's switch. Set the timer to 10 minutes when you start using the geyser. You're underestimating how much effort it will take for you to **acquire the skills needed to build your own timer**. If you want to regularly build electronics projects then that is time well spend. If you just want to build this timer then it will not be worth your time.

Comment: @Hearth Geyser is an electric appliance, which heats water. google it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie understood brother, will google about the price of an egg timer.

Comment: An electronic Egg timer is about $ 3 : https://www.ebay.com/itm/1pc-Electronic-Digital-LCD-Magnetic-Countdown-Timer-Count-Down-Egg-Kitchen/114523968406?hash=item1aaa291396:g:cO8AAOSw5wRfs5zq&var=414713445376

Comment: @saurabhgupta at least in US english, geyser refers specifically to a geological feature where high-pressure water periodically erupts from the ground; I've never heard it applied to any sort of appliance. I assume it's one of those words that means something different in different dialects!

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly a mechanical problem if you intend to start the alarm timer automatically. As we don’t have any information on that, I’ll assume that there is either a low voltage contact closure or mains is applied when the timer is supposed to start.

So now the problem is reduced to making an alarm indication 10 minutes after the start.

An easy solution would be to use an Arduino board. You could either program the board using the Arduino IDE or
or use something like the gcc tool chain  to write a bare metal program for the AVR chip.

All the program has to do is delay for 10 minutes and the generate whatever indicator you want, such as a port pin changing state to drive a relay through a transistor or a 2kHz signal to drive a beeper.

The program could be as simple as using library delay and PWM functions, or you could delve deep into the datasheet and use timer peripherals and interrupts. Adding a countdown display might be nice, though it starts to look a bit suspicious.